# Android TextView history

Tags: android, autocomplete, textview

What type of textview should I use so that everytime i touch it, it will display the most recent entries used in a dropdown box? AutoComplete and MultiAutoComplete are confusing to me...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Auto Complete Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html) will help you. If user writes something to textView and submit it, then you can save this string to a file. And if you add this to the string array which mentioned in tutorial, auto complete dropdown will appear...

Comment: But I don't want to have to type anything. When the box is selected, I want the suggestions to pull up.